# how to draw multiple lines simultaneously with vtk?

Tags: c++, vtk

the goal is to draw lines from several points
I have 2 vector tab_recupere_P1 and tab_recupere_P2 , the size of each vector is 14.
 I browse through the two vector and I get at each iteration the PP1 and PP2 point to build a line.

I used several methods but all have given the same result

here is my code: method 1:

```
for ( std::vector<Coord_point*>::iterator i = tab_recupere_P1.begin();
                       i != tab_recupere_P1.end();
                       ++i)
{   
   new_p = *i;
   pp1[0] = new_p->p0[0];
   pp1[1] = new_p->p0[1];
   pp1[2] = new_p->p0[2];

   std::cout << " x : "<< pp1[0] << " y : " << pp1[1] << " z : " << pp1[2]  <<std::endl;

   for ( std::vector<Coord_point*>::iterator j = tab_recupere_P2.begin();
                       j != tab_recupere_P2.end();
                       j++)
   {    
    new_p2 = *j;
   pp2[0] = new_p2->p0[0];
   pp2[1] = new_p2->p0[1];
   pp2[2] = new_p2->p0[2];

   std::cout << " x2 : "<< pp2[0] << " y2 : " << pp2[1] << " z2 : " << pp2[2] <<std::endl;


   // Add the two poitns to a vtkPoints object
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> pts = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
  pts->InsertNextPoint(pp1);
  pts->InsertNextPoint(pp2);

 // Create a line between the two points
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkLine> line = 
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkLine>::New();
 for(unsigned int h = 0; h < 2; h++)
 {
line->GetPointIds()->SetId(h,h);
}

// Create a cell array to store the line in
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> lines = 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();
lines->InsertNextCell(line);

// Create a polydata to store everything in
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> pdata = 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();

 // Add the points to the dataset
 pdata->SetPoints(pts);

 // Add the lines to the dataset
 pdata->SetLines(lines);

  #if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
  mapper->SetInput(pdata);
  #else
  mapper->SetInputData(pdata);
  #endif

  actor->SetMapper(mapper);
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = 
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = 
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
 renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
 renderWindowInteractorLine->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

 renderer->AddActor(actor);
 ui.qvtkWidget_Visualisation->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow); 
 ui.qvtkWidget_Visualisation->update(); 
 renderWindowInteractorLine->Initialize();


 renderWindowInteractorLine->Start();

 break;

 }
}
```

method numbre 2 : I store the lines in a vector and then I get to draw each line

```
for ( std::vector<Coord_point*>::iterator i = tab_recupere_P1.begin();
                       i != tab_recupere_P1.end();
                       ++i)
{   
   new_p = *i;
   pp1[0] = new_p->p0[0];
   pp1[1] = new_p->p0[1];
   pp1[2] = new_p->p0[2];

   std::cout << " x : "<< pp1[0] << " y : " << pp1[1] << " z : " << pp1[2]  <<std::endl;

   for ( std::vector<Coord_point*>::iterator j = tab_recupere_P2.begin();
                       j != tab_recupere_P2.end();
                       j++)
 {  
    new_p2 = *j;
   pp2[0] = new_p2->p0[0];
   pp2[1] = new_p2->p0[1];
   pp2[2] = new_p2->p0[2];

   std::cout << " x2 : "<< pp2[0] << " y2 : " << pp2[1] << " z2 : " << pp2[2] <<std::endl;

vtkSmartPointer<vtkLineSource> lineSource = 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkLineSource>::New();
 lineSource->SetPoint1(pp1);
 lineSource->SetPoint2(pp2);
 lineSource->Update();
 tab_lineSource.push_back(lineSource);


 break;

  }
 }
vtkSmartPointer<vtkLineSource> new_lineSource = 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkLineSource>::New();
for ( std::vector<vtkLineSource*>::iterator l = tab_lineSource.begin();
                       l != tab_lineSource.end();
                       l++)
{   
new_lineSource = *l;
 mapper->SetInputConnection(new_lineSource->GetOutputPort());
 actor->SetMapper(mapper);
 actor->GetProperty()->SetLineWidth(1);
 actor->GetProperty()->SetColor(1,0,0);

 vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = 
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = 
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
 renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
 renderWindowInteractorLine->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

  renderer->AddActor(actor);
  ui.qvtkWidget_Visualisation->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow); 
 ui.qvtkWidget_Visualisation->updateGeometry(); 
  renderWindowInteractorLine->Initialize();

 renderWindowInteractorLine->Start();
 }
```

the problem that whatever the method, the line of the first iteration will be drawn and there is no error message. but what is required is to draw all the lines from points stored in vectors.

Can you help me please!!please!!

Comment: Could you paste the output you see due to the cout statements in both cases?

Comment: Also, in the second example, you have a break in the nested for loop that's going to terminate it after the first iteration. This is probably not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things wrong with both examples.

In example 1:

- You have a break at the end of the inner loop. This will terminate the inner loop after its first execution.
- You create new lines, polydata, and a new renderer with each loop!

In example 2:

- You again have that break in the inner loop that's going to terminate it after its first execution.
- Again you create a whole bunch of VTK classes (including a renderer and a renderwindow) during every loop iteration, whilst you should create them once before and outside of both loops.

There's much more wrong with this code. You should start with a much simpler example. Also try indenting your code, it's really hard to read (also for you) this way.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I changed the method: I created a class named Point and I store each instance in a dynamic array and I get the values ​​with success.

Comment: but I wanted to know is that it is possible to draw several lines simultaneously with vtkLineSource, if possible, can you give me an example please .thank you